# From list shown below - highlight in BOLD the pair with the highest value

Tags: list-manipulation

I have been trying for sometime to achieve the following:-
Given the list - {{"E", 3}, {"D", 2}, {"S", 2}, {"M", 2}} a list of pairs which maybe 4 pairs - more or less... This list is an output of a previous calculation - so the result can be different every calculation.
I need the output list shown above to highlight in BOLD the pair with the highest value.
Thus the result would look like  -  {**{"E", 3}**, {"D", 2}, {"S", 2}, {"M", 2}} in this case.
I am sure the answer is so simple, but I can't find it.
Please could anyone advise how to do this with coding.
Many thanks for your help & suggestions.

Comment: `highlightLargest[list_List,f_:Last]:=With[{max=First@TakeLargestBy[list,f,1]},Map[If[#===max,Style[#,Bold],#]&,list]]` should do the trick but the output of this can not be used computationally anymore (unless one removes the `Style` wrapper from the largest element with e.g. a rule like `Style[x_, ___] :> x`.

Comment: I request you to take a look at the book written by the inventor; [Chapter 7](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/07-colors-and-styles.html) specifically.

Comment: If you have your result in a variable called `list`, you can use `MapAt[Style[#, Bold] &, list, OrderingBy[list, Last, -1]]`

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's help - I think this answer works best for my situation - MapAt[Style[#, Bold] &, list, OrderingBy[list, Last, -1]]  Many thanks Ben Izd

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: If @BenIzd doesn't post an answer, feel free to post your solution as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can highlight the largest case with `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[Style[#, Bold] &, list, OrderingBy[list, Last, -1]]
```

In the last argument, I used `OrderingBy` to find the index of the largest element.